# .htaccess doesn't work with CSS files

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` file with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I also have a `Router.php` file:

```
<?php

class Router
{
    function __construct()
    {
        print_r($_GET);
        $this->request = $_GET['url'];
        $this->request = rtrim($this->request, "/");
        $this->params = explode("/", $this->request);
        print_r($this->params);
        $this->controller = $this->params[0];
        if ($this->controller == "index.php")
            $this->controller = "Index";
        $this->controller = ucfirst($this->controller);
        $file = 'controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require_once $file;
            $this->connection = new $this->controller($this->params);
        } else {
            $file = 'controllers/PageNotFound.php';
            $this->controller = "PageNotFound";
            require_once $file;
            $this->connection = new $this->controller();
        }
    }
}
```

and `header.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>System stypendialny</title>
</head>
<body>
```

I have a problem with the `.htaccess` file. When I use this version of the file and I try this http://localhost/scholarship_system/ URL in the browser I see this:

> Array ( )
>       Notice: Undefined index: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\scholarship_system\libs\Router.php on line 8
>       Array ( [0] => )

But when I remove this line (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) then the CSS file is not loaded.

Comment: `$_GET['url]` only exists if the file you're trying to access doesn't (that's when you RewriteRule gets triggered). If the folder `/scholarship_system/ ` exists and there's a `index.php` in that folder it will use it straight away without the rewrite.

Comment: That's right, but if I remove line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

I get this in $_GET Array ( [url] => index.php )

Comment: That will give you more issues with your css, images and other assets. I've added an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your .htaccess as it is. If you remove -f condition, you're router will need to handle all requests to css, images and javascript-files as well and that's just a pain.

Set a default controller in your Router-class instead:

```
$this->request = isset($_GET['url'])? $_GET['url] : 'default';
```

then you just need to create the file `controllers/default.php` which will be used if the `$_GET['url]` isn't set.

Comment: Ok. When I write this http://localhost/scholarship_system or http://localhost/scholarship_system/index everything is ok. But when I write this http://localhost/scholarship_system/index/ or http://localhost/scholarship_system/hello/hey the file css is not attached.

Comment: You're currently loading your css-file relative from URL: `href="resources/style.css"`, Change it to absolute: `href="/resources/style.css"`(prepending the path with a `/`)